# Looking for recommendations for streaming lots of data/files through WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, streaming, blob

We are looking at streaming 1000's of files in order back to the consuming client.  I have put together different options including using the WCF Streamed Transfermode option but find there is sever lag when having to wait for all data to be pre-assembled due to the required order.

Therefore, it appears there needs to be a need for some type of chunking data back to the client as it becomes available.

I have tried to avoid putting the concurrency and data assembly (for ordering) on the service side and off the client due to possible client hardware capabilities, but that might not be available.

**UPDATED** These are mainly images that we are displaying and we have attempted a number of setups 1) acquiring all images and streaming them in one stream - worked well but the time required to get all files and assemble was way to long, 2) acquiring each image separately - this worked way to slow.

Any recommendations?

Comment: Why don't you chunk requests on a client side (One request -> One file)?

Comment: @igor, thanks. Yes I have tried that.  Unfortunately, we are displaying these files/images and the speed is slow.  Updated post with additional info.

Answer (score 0):

You say "images that we are displaying". 1000 images displayed at the same time in a full HD monitor give an average image size of 45x45. They are probably too small even for a thumbnail gallery.

If you show images in sequence (or in multiple windows) you don't need to send 1000 images at a time, but while user sees the first image (or first 5-10 for example), you can start sending the others in background (since user can't see them at the moment).

If you have a thumbnail gallery, you can send many thumbnails (faster since they're smaller wrt the original images), then you send the image user want to see in detail when he clicks on it.